# How to get cocos2d to draw all rectangles in an array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

How can I draw all the rectangles in a CGRect array? The code I have so far is:
in my init method:

> `rec1 = CGRectMake(50, 400, 30, 30);`
>   `CGRect startingRect = rec1;`
>   `int count = 48;`
>   `CGRect rectArray[count];`
>   `rectArray[0] = startingRect;`
>   `CGRect oneRect = rectArray[0];`
>   `int i;`
>   `for (i = 1; i < count; i++) {`
>   `oneRect.origin.x += 40;`
>   `if (oneRect.origin.x+oneRect.size.width > size.width) {`
>   `oneRect.origin.x = startingRect.origin.x;`
>   `oneRect.origin.y -= 40;`
>   `}`
>   `rectArray[i] = oneRect;`
>   `}`
>   `[self draw];`

in my draw method:

> `glColor4f(1.0, 0, 0, 1.0);`
>   `glLineWidth(1.0f);`
>   `[self drawRectange:rec1];`

and in my drawRectangle method:

> `glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);`
>   `CGPoint vertices[4] = {`
>    `ccp(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y),`
>    `ccp(rect.origin.x+rect.size.width, rect.origin.y),`
>    `ccp(rect.origin.x+rect.size.width, rect.origin.y+rect.size.height),`
>    `ccp(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y+rect.size.height)`
>   `};`
>   `ccDrawPoly(vertices, 4, YES);`
>   `glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);`
>   `CC_ENABLE_DEFAULT_GL_STATES();`

The problem is, since the draw method overrides the original (at least thats what i think it does), i can't modify it to accept a CGRect parameter so it can send a message to the drawRentangle method for each rect. Can someone please help me? Many thanks.

Comment: Instead of overriding it, have it call another method which accesses your array or each rectangle?

Comment: I tried that but I guess it has to us the draw method because when I created a new method it didn't draw the rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect rectArray[count];
NSUInteger index = count;
while (index--)
 UIRectFrame(rectArray[index]);
```

Comment: I don't know what that does but it didn't work. I'm using cocos2d too so no core graphic stuff and I can't find a simple way to draw a grid of dots.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using `NSMutableArray` as an instance variable so that it can be accessed in the draw method?